# Compatible AES encryption and decryption for C# and javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

I am trying to write two classes in C# and Javascript which I can use throughout my project to encrypt or decrypt data using AES when data is exchanged.

Using AES I am embedding the Salt (32 bytes) and IV (16 bytes) in the encrypted result, this works fine for both classes individually when testing. Adding the Salt and IV to the mix doesn't bring up a lot of references to get this working between the two platforms.

For C# I am using the standard System.Security.Crypthography.AES

```
 private static readonly int iterations = 1000;

    public static string Encrypt(string input, string password)
    {
        byte[] encrypted;
        byte[] IV;
        byte[] Salt = GetSalt();
        byte[] Key = CreateKey(password, Salt);

        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            aesAlg.GenerateIV();
            IV = aesAlg.IV;

            var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        swEncrypt.Write(input);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

        byte[] combinedIvSaltCt = new byte[Salt.Length + IV.Length + encrypted.Length];
        Array.Copy(Salt, 0, combinedIvSaltCt, 0, Salt.Length);
        Array.Copy(IV, 0, combinedIvSaltCt, Salt.Length, IV.Length);
        Array.Copy(encrypted, 0, combinedIvSaltCt, Salt.Length + IV.Length, encrypted.Length);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(combinedIvSaltCt.ToArray());
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string input, string password)
    {
        byte[] inputAsByteArray;
        string plaintext = null;
        try
        {
            inputAsByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(input);

            byte[] Salt = new byte[32];
            byte[] IV = new byte[16];
            byte[] Encoded = new byte[inputAsByteArray.Length - Salt.Length - IV.Length];

            Array.Copy(inputAsByteArray, 0, Salt, 0, Salt.Length);
            Array.Copy(inputAsByteArray, Salt.Length, IV, 0, IV.Length);
            Array.Copy(inputAsByteArray, Salt.Length + IV.Length, Encoded, 0, Encoded.Length);

            byte[] Key = CreateKey(password, Salt);

            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;
                aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(Encoded))
                {
                    using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return plaintext;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static byte[] CreateKey(string password, byte[] salt)
    {
        using (var rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, iterations))
            return rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(32);
    }

    private static byte[] GetSalt()
    {
        var salt = new byte[32];
        using (var random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            random.GetNonZeroBytes(salt);
        }

        return salt;
    }
```

For the Javascript solution I am using CryptoJS, based upon this reference http://www.adonespitogo.com/articles/encrypting-data-with-cryptojs-aes/

```
    var keySize = 256;
var ivSize = 128;
var saltSize = 256;
var iterations = 1000;

var message = "Hello World";
var password = "Secret Password";


function encrypt (msg, pass) {
  var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(saltSize/8);

  var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(pass, salt, {
      keySize: keySize/32,
      iterations: iterations
    });

  var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(ivSize/8);

  var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(msg, key, { 
    iv: iv, 
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC

  });

  // salt, iv will be hex 32 in length
  // append them to the ciphertext for use  in decryption
  var transitmessage = salt + iv + encrypted;
  return transitmessage.toString();
}

function decrypt (transitmessage, pass) {
  var salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(transitmessage.substr(0, 64));
  var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(transitmessage.substr(64, 32));
  var encrypted = transitmessage.substring(96);

  var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(pass, salt, {
      keySize: keySize/32,
      iterations: iterations
    });

  var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, { 
    iv: iv, 
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC

  })
  return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
```

Used password: `Secret Password`

C# outcome:
`r7Oi1vMXZ5mYJay8i+slbJZEiT3CxV/1zOYntbZIsS5RuasABJKQQQVvAe50U1deIIqyQiwzQWYelMJ48WWpMQ==`

Javascript outcome: `72ff8e7b653efbe3101d2c4ca7d7fe1af06652b907a90281aafa5ae09b45c9af091571b08d3d39cbad129939488319b2pprMQFFEJZR5JlrDsMqT8w==`

The outcome should be `Hello World`

Both solutions work well within their own environment, however the C# or Javascript hashes can't be exchanged, they will not decrypt. My guess is that the character encoding has something to do with it, hence why the base64 sizes differ so much. Does anyone have a idea to get this working together? Thanks!

Comment: Consider adding a version identifier, it can be as simple as a single byte. This will allow you to gracefully change/upgrade in the future. Also missing is authentication of the encryption, this is necessary if there is the possibility of the wrong key ever being used and/or an attacker making changed to the encrypted message. For an example see [RNCryptor-Spec](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-Spec/blob/master/RNCryptor-Spec-v3.md) or just use [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor) which supports multiple languages and platforms.

Comment: The first part of the javascript output looks suspiciously like hex encoding rather than base64 encoding.

Comment: Indeed! Taking the first 64 bytes as hex would be 32-binary bytes equaling the salt length, Taking the next 32 bytes as hex would be 16- binary bytes equaling the IV length. Taking the last 24 bytes as Base64 and decoding into binary yields 16 binary bytes and that would be the encrypted message padded to one block size which is in hex: `A69ACC405144259479265AC3B0CA93F3`. Adjust the encodings to match.

Comment: As James K Polk pointed out, the first part is definitely hex. I adjusted all the encodings for the Javascript solution. I'll post my result in case someone else has some use for it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The error was in the Javascript code, the first part was Hex while the end was the encrypted result in Base64.

The following Javascript code makes the AES results interchangeable with the C# solution provided above. I had some difficulties making sure that all the results where properly encoded and decoded in Hex, so there are some new functions.

```
var keySize = 256;
var ivSize = 128;
var saltSize = 256;
var iterations = 1000;

var message = "Does this work?";
var password = "Secret Password";


function encrypt (msg, pass) {
  var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(saltSize/8);

  var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(pass, salt, {
      keySize: keySize/32,
      iterations: iterations
    });

  var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(ivSize/8);

  var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(msg, key, { 
    iv: iv, 
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC

  });

    var encryptedHex = base64ToHex(encrypted.toString());
    var base64result = hexToBase64(salt + iv + encryptedHex);


  return base64result;
}

function decrypt (transitmessage, pass) {

  var hexResult = base64ToHex(transitmessage)

  var salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hexResult.substr(0, 64));
  var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hexResult.substr(64, 32));
  var encrypted = hexToBase64(hexResult.substring(96));

  var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(pass, salt, {
      keySize: keySize/32,
      iterations: iterations
    });

  var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, { 
    iv: iv, 
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC

  })

  return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8); 
}

function hexToBase64(str) {
  return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,
    str.replace(/\r|\n/g, "").replace(/([\da-fA-F]{2}) ?/g, "0x$1 ").replace(/ +$/, "").split(" "))
  );
}

function base64ToHex(str) {
  for (var i = 0, bin = atob(str.replace(/[ \r\n]+$/, "")), hex = []; i < bin.length; ++i) {
    var tmp = bin.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
    if (tmp.length === 1) tmp = "0" + tmp;
    hex[hex.length] = tmp;
  }
  return hex.join("");
}
```

Comment: Great solution! However, but how can you hide the password in JS? For now, it's "Secret password", but anyone can see that, right (I know, it's JS, etc etc etc)? Did you do some other approach to generate some random password? Because, if you generate a random password in JS, on C# side, you would have to know the same new generated password, right?

Comment: You might want to take a look at ECDH: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman. Also there are browser techniques in-place to store secrets https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/

Comment: what a life saver , thanks mate :) +1

Answer (score 2):

Going into 2023, some modifications to @usselite's answer are required to make it work.

The biggest change is that the default encryption method in cryptojs has changed from SHA1 to SHA256, while the default in c# is still SHA1. Therefore, the CreateKey method portion of the questioner's C# code has gone through this change below before it can be used:

```
public static byte[] CreateKey(string password, byte[] salt)
    {
        int iterations = 1000;

        using (var rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, iterations, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256))
            return rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(32);
    }
```

As you can see, I added this line of code：HashAlgorithmName.SHA256 to specify the encryption method.

Answer (score -2):

You are using [Cipher Block Chaining (CBC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_(CBC)) mode with a random IV (correct way).

Indirectly the IV will affect every plaintext block before the encryption.
Therefore comparing the content of the encrypted data will not help you here.

The length of the encrypted data is also different. I assume this is because the `CryptoJS.lib.WordArray` will be printed in hex.
Therefore You are getting `seed` and `IV` in hex encoding and the encrypted message in base64 encoding.

On C# side there is only one base64 encoded result containing everything.

In general plain CBC mode is no longer state-of-the-art encryption (e.g. for TLS1.3 alls ciphers with AES-CBC has been removed). Under certain conditions it may allows certain attacks (e.g. padding oracle attack). Therefore I would recommend to use an authenticating cipher mode like GCM mode instead.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Further, I did **not** point out CBC mode as outdated. GCM mode is generally a better choice **if it is supported** on all the platforms needed but that is not the case. Also not all use cases require authenticated encryption as I did point out.

Comment: GCM  mode is not the silver bullet. CBC-HMAC eliminates a padding oracle attack and such an attack may not be an issue. GCM mode is not practically better than CBC-HMAC but is easier to use but also susceptible to nonce reuse. See [Practical disadvantages of GCM mode encryption](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10775/practical-disadvantages-of-gcm-mode-encryption) and [Breaking https' AES-GCM (or a part of it)](https://www.cryptologie.net/article/361/breaking-https-aes-gcm-or-a-part-of-it/), Google for more.

Comment: @zaph: GCM was just one example for an authenticating cipher. The problem of CBC-HMAC is that it is just a MAC algorithm, not a complete cipher. It is hard enough to make the developers use a cipher correctly but use a cipher plus apply a CBC-MAC in a correct way (key derivation for encryption and MAC, random hmac key, ...) - good luck.

Comment: 1. My complaint is that you make to strong a case, stronger than warranted. In my first comment is stated "GCM mode is generally a better choice" if available. At least one major cell phone provider sadly does not provide GCM mode and that presents interoperability difficulties. 2. Yes it is difficult for developers to get CBC correct along with many other mistakes. To a lesser extent it is easy to get the GCM nonce correct. 3. The issue with TLS and CBC is that it is MAC-then-encrypt, not encrypt-them-MAC. See [Cryptographic Doom](https://moxie.org/blog/the-cryptographic-doom-principle/).